# "Dracaena reflexa" aka Song of India almost lost all its leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, leaves, watering, dracaena

My *Dracaena reflexa* plant which I got a month back lost all its leaves. I have been watering only if the top soil is dry and have kept it in a window sill. Initial two weeks it was inside my living room with full bushy leaves...[image]but it slowly started losing its leaves, so I placed it in a south facing window with moderate indirect bright sunlight. Yet no use. It has lost almost all the leaves now with its trunk standing erect. I even mist the trunk and the leaves everyday after reading a few tips..no luck. How do I save my plant in this stage? [image] I so badly want it to be revived. Any help/ suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I think you overwatered it, and the roots are rotting because of that. Try to let all the soil dry in between waterings.